# value frequency as a column after group by

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, unique-values

I am trying to mark the frequency of identical value (year) in a dataframe and to show it as a column in the original dataframe. Prior to that I need to group all the rows based on another column.
This is dummy data, in principle, I have many more columns and rows. This is what I have done but I do not know how to map it back to the original dataframe (into a separate column)

```
data1 = [[1, 'Tom', 1987], [1, 'Bill', 1987], [1, 'Andrew', 1988],[2, 'Ann', 1994], [2, 'Olya', 1984], [2, 'Andrew', 1984], [2, 'Tony', 1989]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['group', 'name', 'year'])
unique_year = df1.groupby(['group'])['year'].apply(lambda s: s.value_counts())
freq = unique_year.to_frame()
freq

group   year    

1       1987    2
        1988    1
2       1984    2
        1994    1
        1989    1
```

This is the desired result:

```
group   name    year    year_frequency
1       Tom        1987        2
1       Bill       1987        2
1       Andrew     1988        1
2       Ann        1994        1
2       Olya       1984        2
2       Andrew     1984        2
2       Tony       1989        1
```

I am sorry for the lack of clarity, I am very new to pandas.

Comment: `df1['year_frequency'] = df1.groupby(['group','year'])['year'].transform('count')`

Comment: sorry for confusion, it worked after i tried it again. Thank you!